# Fastest way to get a large number of nodes from Neo4j using py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to load nodes (about 400) and relationships (about 800) from a Neo4j DB to create a force directed graph using D3. This is my get function (I'm using Tornado):

```
def get(self):
        query_string = "START r=rel(*) RETURN r"
        query = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db, query_string)
        results = query.execute().data
        start = set([r[0].start_node for r in results])
        end = set([r[0].end_node for r in results])
        nodes_to_keep = list(start.union(end))
        nodes = []
        for n in nodes_to_keep:
            nodes.append({
                "name":n['name'].encode('utf-8'), 
                "group":n['type'].encode('utf-8'), 
                "description":n['description'].encode('utf-8'), 
                "node":int(n['node_id'])})
        #links
        links = []
        for r in results:
            links.append({"source":int(r[0].start_node['node_id']), "target":int(r[0].end_node['node_id'])})
        self.render(
            "index.html",
            page_title='My Page',
            page_heading='Sweet D3 Force Diagram',
            nodes=nodes,
            links =links,
        )
```

I'm thinking the expensive process is in `for n in nodes_to_keep:` and the `for r in results:` since every time I get each property, that's a trip to the server. Right?

What's the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the above process is taking so long is because every time I ask for a node property, I'm taking a trip to the server to fetch something out of the database. I was able to drastically reduce the time this process takes by simply modifying the Cypher query.

For instance, to get all nodes with relationships I used this query:

```
query_string = """MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) 
                RETURN n, n.node_id, n.name, n.type, n.description, m.node_id, m.name, m.type, m.description""" 
query = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db, query_string)
results = query.execute().data
```

The results contain the information I need, so I just loop through the results to get the properties.

The takeaway is that you need to write your queries such that they get you the info you need the first time around.